# cPanel JSON API2 editzonerecord issue

Tags: php, json, api, cpanel

I'm trying to edit the A record of one of the zone files using the cPanel API2 but I am having a weird problem. Instead of replacing the the entry its adding a new one. My call to the API is as follows:

```
https://1.2.3.4:2087/json-api/editzonerecord?domain=mydomain.com&line=13&name=mydomain.com.&address=1.2.3.5&type=A&ttl=300
```

So instead of replacing line 13 (which houses the A record) from 1.2.3.4 to 1.2.3.5 its adding another entry above the original. So the zone file ends up looking like so:

```
(..)
(13) mydomain.com.   300     IN   A   1.2.3.5
(14) mydomain.com.   14400   IN   A   1.2.3.4
(..)
```

I have followed the instructions as per http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/EditZoneRecord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Response from cPanel:**

If you are just trying to edit an IP for an record you can omit the name section.

I also found out that if you include the name option and have a wrong line, or the name does not match the record on that line it will make a new line for the record.  I use the command `cat -n /var/named/example.com.db` to retrieve the line numbers for the zone.

Below is the api command that I used that successfully edits the A record for the domain.

```
/json-api/editzonerecord?domain=example.com&line=13&&address=4.3.2.1&type=A&ttl=300
```

Below is my zone file after the edit:

```
 1  ; cPanel first:11.32.4.15 (update_time):1348223931 Cpanel::ZoneFile::VERSION:1.3 hostname:cpanel.test.server latest:11.32.4.15
 2  ; Zone file for example.com
 3  $TTL 14400
 4  example.com.    86400   IN      SOA     ns1.cpcitizenk.com.     citizen.cpanel.net.     (
 5                                                  2012092110 ;Serial Number
 6                                                  86400 ;refresh
 7                                                  7200 ;retry
 8                                                  3600000 ;expire
 9                                                  86400   )
10
11  example.com.    86400   IN      NS      ns1.cpcitizenk.com.
12  example.com.    86400   IN      NS      ns2.cpcitizenk.com.
13  example.com.    300     IN      A       4.3.2.1
14  localhost       14400   IN      A       127.0.0.1
15  example.com.    14400   IN      MX      0       example.com.
16  mail    300     IN      A       1.2.3.4
17  www     14400   IN      CNAME   example.com.
18  ftp     14400   IN      A       1.2.3.4
19  cpanel  14400   IN      A       1.2.3.4
20  whm     14400   IN      A       1.2.3.4
21  webmail 14400   IN      A       1.2.3.4
22  webdisk 14400   IN      A       1.2.3.4
```